# Get Attachment Custom Field value

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom field in my Attachment form for WordPress.

I am storing values in this & would now like to display the value at the public end.

Going by this http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_metadata, this should help, but doesn't:
`<?php wp_get_attachment_metadata( $attachment_id, $unfiltered ); ?>`

Can someone please assist?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wp_get_attachment_metadata result is:

```
Array
(
    [width] =>
    [height] =>
    [file] =>
    [sizes] => Array
        (
            [thumbnail] => Array
                (
                    [file] =>
                    [width] =>
                    [height] =>
                    [mime-type] =>
                )

            [medium] => Array
                (
                    [file] =>
                    [width] =>
                    [height] => 
                    [mime-type] => 
                )

        )

    [image_meta] => Array
        (
            [aperture] => 
            [credit] => 
            [camera] => 
            [caption] => 
            [created_timestamp] => 
            [copyright] => 
            [focal_length] => 
            [iso] => 
            [shutter_speed] => 
            [title] => 
        )

)
```

So, this is attachment datails. But you want get custom fields. You can use same as post:

```
get_post_meta($post->ID, 'your_field_name', true);
```

all of which avaible in attachment.php. In attachment page, $post is attachment post, so not parent post.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have tried `get_post_meta($post->ID, '**my field in here**', true);` and the result is empty. How do I debug this?

Comment: are you sure add custom post meta? normally, in wordpress attachment page not have custom post meta area. you must custom table to it. why do you adding metas?

Comment: Here's a screengrab of the attachment: http://imgur.com/BiSXGxx - both `languages` & `products` are custom fields.

Comment: if is it media page on wp-admin, all is right. you can get meta names with firebug. copy input name and paste it to **my field in here**.

Comment: `<input type="text" class="text" id="attachments-122-product" name="attachments[122][product]" value="product-2">`

Comment: which you use plugin or theme? that is interesting. i will look it in my free time.

Comment: I don't use a plugin for this. Thanks.